# Workaround in this case to keep z-order alive with reduced opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problems to find a good workaround for the default behaviour with element stacking and opacity for the code situation below. I probably have to rearrange some things in my code, but it seems that I can't find an appropriate solution this time and I need some advice.
What do I have to bear in mind or what workaround could work here to permanently force the blue squares with reduced opacity at the topmost position and keep the canvas below?

```js
var rangeVal = document.getElementById('rangevalue');
var updateVal = function(val) {
  rangeVal.innerHTML = val;
};
updateVal(range.value);
var imgBlue = document.getElementsByClassName("page-header")[0];
range.addEventListener("input", function(value) {
    imgBlue.style.opacity = this.value / this.max;
});

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
.page-header:after {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/gkvp6Jn.jpg);
  height:100%; width: 100%; left:80px; top: 90px; content: "";
  z-index:2;  opacity:1; position:fixed; pointer-events:none
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="range" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="1"  
oninput="updateVal(this.value)"
style="position:fixed; top:32px; left:8px">
<div id="rangevalue"></div>
<div class="page-header"></div> 

<div id='div1' style="position:fixed; top:70px; left:100px">
<canvas id='canvas' width='120' height='120'> </canvas> </div>
```

Comment: You want to lower the opacity of the red box too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply increase the z-index of `page-header`. Your issue is that when the opacity decrease you create a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and the [painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#painting-order) of your elements will change:

```js
var rangeVal = document.getElementById('rangevalue');
var updateVal = function(val) {
  rangeVal.innerHTML = val;
};
updateVal(range.value);
var imgBlue = document.getElementsByClassName("page-header")[0];
range.addEventListener("input", function(value) {
    imgBlue.style.opacity = this.value / this.max;
});

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
.page-header {
 position:relative;
 z-index:2;
}

.page-header:after {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/gkvp6Jn.jpg);
  height:100%; width: 100%; left:80px; top: 90px; content: "";
  z-index:2;  opacity:1; position:fixed; pointer-events:none
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="range" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="1"  
oninput="updateVal(this.value)"
style="position:fixed; top:32px; left:8px;">
<div id="rangevalue"></div>
<div class="page-header"></div> 

<div id='div1' style="position:fixed; top:70px; left:100px">
<canvas id='canvas' width='120' height='120'> </canvas> </div>
```